# How to include Classpath jars in WEB-INF/lib Folder while creating a WarFile using Ant Build Script

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build

Am working on creating an ant script for building and deploying the project. Project Structure is as follows:

```
    Projectname
    --src
    --tst
    --lib ( I have 5 jars here)
    --resources
    --WebContent
          --META-INF
          --WEB-INF
               --lib (I have 3 jars here)
               --properties
               --templates
               --stylesheets
               --web.xml
```

when I create a war file using the ant script,the structure of the war file should be as follows:

```
--WEB-INF
    --classes
    --lib (should contain all the jar files from the entire project. ie, jars from the lib folders of the project and also the classpath)
--META-INF
    --MANIFEST.MF
```

But when I build the project, the war file created has the following structure which is incorrect, I want the structure to be similar to the one above.

```
--WEB-INF
   --classes
   --lib( is containing the jars that are in the lib folders of the project but it should also contain the classpath jars)
--META-INF
  --MANIFEST.MF
--abc.jar { These are the classpath jars that should also be in the WEB-INF/lib folder but they are not)
--xyz.jar
--mnf.jar
--qrs.jar


Here is the code snippet am using to create the WAR file in the build.xml file.
<target name="war" description="Bundles the application as a WAR file" depends="build">
        <echo> === PACKAGE WAR ====== </echo>
         <delete dir="target" failonerror="false"/>
         <mkdir dir="target"/>
        <war destfile="target/test.war" needxmlfile="false" >
            <fileset dir="WebContent">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
            <path>  
            <path refid="MobileServices.classpath"/>
            <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar">
            </fileset>          
            </path> 
            <classes dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes"/>
        </war>
```

Am using the `<path refid="> to include the classpath jars in the warfile.`
Anyhelp is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using 
<fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar">

</fileset>

Try

<lib dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar">

</lib>

and move it outside of the path tag.

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html